# react render component in recursive way

Tags: reactjs

I have below JSON with me,

{

```
              "accountHierarchy": [
                {
                  "account": {
                    "accountId": "2-AIOFRVT",
                    "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                    "accountNumber": "ZE2004-49874",
                    "organisation": null,
                    "tradingName": null,
                    "masterAccount": null,
                    "parentAccount": null,
                    "primaryContact": null,
                    "systemId": null,
                    "isRelated": null,
                    "type": "Owner",
                    "location": "OWNER (ZE2004-49874)"
                  },
                  "childAccounts": [
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "2-AWYZLCL",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE2008-04508",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Service",
                        "location": "5 STERKBOS STREET (ZE2008-04508)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": [
                        {
                          "account": {
                            "accountId": "2-TEST123",
                            "accountName": "This is test account",
                            "accountNumber": "ZE1111-12345",
                            "organisation": "",
                            "tradingName": "",
                            "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                            "systemId": null,
                            "isRelated": null,
                            "type": "Service",
                            "location": "New test account (ZE1111-12345)"
                          },
                          "childAccounts": []
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "2-AVDAQSV",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE2007-03590",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Service",
                        "location": "160 AMCOR ROAD (ZE2007-03590)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": null
                    },
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "2-AX3QDZK",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE2008-04558",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Service",
                        "location": "LONE HILL (ZE2008-04558)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": null
                    },
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "1-4AM7S51",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE1410-09777",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "2-9I4HPB8",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Owner",
                        "location": "OWNER (ZE1410-09777)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": [
                        {
                          "account": {
                            "accountId": "2-TEST456",
                            "accountName": "This is test account",
                            "accountNumber": "ZE1111-6789",
                            "organisation": "",
                            "tradingName": "",
                            "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                            "systemId": null,
                            "isRelated": null,
                            "type": "Service",
                            "location": "Testing (ZE1111-6789)"
                          },
                          "childAccounts": []
                        }
                    ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "successful": false,
            "code": 0
```

I would like to parse It in react and render recursive manner..The sample screenshot is below,
Can anybody help me how could I write code in recursive way as there can be child inside child.
I have written code in Iterative way but It wont work for the JSON which have multiple child inside child

[image]

I have tried code as below,

1. I have created SelectLocation.jsx and code is as below,

class SelectLocation extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        selectlocationlist: {
            
              "accountHierarchy": [
                {
                  "account": {
                    "accountId": "2-AIOFRVT",
                    "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                    "accountNumber": "ZE2004-49874",
                    "organisation": null,
                    "tradingName": null,
                    "masterAccount": null,
                    "parentAccount": null,
                    "primaryContact": null,
                    "systemId": null,
                    "isRelated": null,
                    "type": "Owner",
                    "location": "OWNER (ZE2004-49874)"
                  },
                  "childAccounts": [
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "2-AWYZLCL",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE2008-04508",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Service",
                        "location": "5 STERKBOS STREET (ZE2008-04508)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": [
                        {
                          "account": {
                            "accountId": "2-TEST123",
                            "accountName": "This is test account",
                            "accountNumber": "ZE1111-12345",
                            "organisation": "",
                            "tradingName": "",
                            "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                            "systemId": null,
                            "isRelated": null,
                            "type": "Service",
                            "location": "New test account (ZE1111-12345)"
                          },
                          "childAccounts": []
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "2-AVDAQSV",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE2007-03590",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Service",
                        "location": "160 AMCOR ROAD (ZE2007-03590)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": null
                    },
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "2-AX3QDZK",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE2008-04558",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Service",
                        "location": "LONE HILL (ZE2008-04558)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": null
                    },
                    {
                      "account": {
                        "accountId": "1-4AM7S51",
                        "accountName": "TEST BUSINESS TEST ACCOUNT",
                        "accountNumber": "ZE1410-09777",
                        "organisation": "",
                        "tradingName": "",
                        "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                        "primaryContact": "2-9I4HPB8",
                        "systemId": null,
                        "isRelated": null,
                        "type": "Owner",
                        "location": "OWNER (ZE1410-09777)"
                      },
                      "childAccounts": [
                        {
                          "account": {
                            "accountId": "2-TEST456",
                            "accountName": "This is test account",
                            "accountNumber": "ZE1111-6789",
                            "organisation": "",
                            "tradingName": "",
                            "masterAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "parentAccount": "2-AIOFRVT",
                            "primaryContact": "No Match Row Id",
                            "systemId": null,
                            "isRelated": null,
                            "type": "Service",
                            "location": "Testing (ZE1111-6789)"
                          },
                          "childAccounts": []
                        }
                    ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "successful": false,
            "code": 0,
            "successful": false,
            "code": 0
          }
}

    



render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {
                this.state.selectlocationlist && this.state.selectlocationlist.accountHierarchy && this.state.selectlocationlist.accountHierarchy.map((accountIterate) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <SelectLocationItem key = {accountIterate.account.accountId} value={accountIterate} callfrom="PARENT" inputlist = {this.state.selectlocationlist} />
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))
            }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

export default SelectLocation;

2.I have written SelectLocationItem as follows,
class SelectLocationItem extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        togglechild : false
    }
} 

svghandler = (inputlist, inputvalue,checkboxvalue) => {
    this.setState({
        togglechild : !checkboxvalue
    })
    
}
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {/* { */}
            {/* this.props.callfrom == "PARENT" ? */}
            <div className="TC">
                
                {this.props.value.childAccounts != undefined && <svg onClick={(e) => this.svghandler(this.props.inputlist, this.props.value.account.accountId,this.state.togglechild)} focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" className="icon toggle-sign"> <use xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" href={this.state.togglechild ? "#icon-add-or-minus" : "#icon-add-or-plus"}></use></svg>}
                <label className="check-TC" onClick={() => this.svghandler(this.props.inputlist, this.props.value.account.accountId)} >
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" className="icon top-svg"><use xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" href="#icon-tick"></use></svg>
                </label>
                <label className="TC-URL">{this.props.value.account.accountName}</label>
                <label className="TC-URL">{this.props.value.account.location}</label>
                { this.state.togglechild && 
                    <div className="childitem">
                    {
                        this.props.value.childAccounts && this.props.value.childAccounts.map((accountIterate) => (
                            <SelectLocationItemChild key="123" value={accountIterate} callfrom="CHILD" />
                        ))
                    }
                    </div>
                }
                

            </div>
            
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

export default SelectLocationItem;

3.I have written SelectLocationItemChild,

class SelectLocationItemChild extends Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

    }
}

svghandler = (inputlist, inputvalue,checkboxvalue) => {
    alert('Welcome to SVG handler :'+inputvalue);
}


render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="TC">
                <svg onClick={() => this.svghandler(this.props.inputlist, this.props.value.account.accountId)} focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" className="icon toggle-sign"> <use xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" href={this.props.value.childAccounts != undefined ? "#icon-add-or-plus" : ""}></use></svg>
                <label className="check-TC" onClick={() => this.svghandler(this.props.inputlist, this.props.value.account.accountId)} >
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" className="icon top-svg"><use xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" href="#icon-tick"></use></svg>
                </label>
                <label className="TC-URL">{this.props.value.account.accountName}</label>
                <label className="TC-URL">{this.props.value.account.location}</label>
                <div className="childitem">
                {
                    this.props.value.childAccounts && this.props.value.childAccounts.map((accountIterate) => (
                        <SelectLocationItem key="123" value={accountIterate} callfrom="CHILD" />
                    ))
                }
                </div>

            </div>


        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

export default SelectLocationItemChild;

so It is rendering and that Image I am posting for reference

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim : I have shared my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. I kept it very simple.

```
const AccountHierarchy = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.accountHierarchy.map(account =>
        <li key={account.account.accountId}><Account account={account} /></li>
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}

const Account = ({ account }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {account.account.accountName}
      <ul>
        {account.childAccounts && account.childAccounts.map(account =>
          <li key={account.account.accountId}><Account account={account} /></li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

[image]